# We choose 2 different people - what is the probability that they all have the same color of the eyes

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

So I have big problems with the problem above... I tried for like 5 hours to find the solution but I just don't know how to proceed. So, there are 45 people, and 5 eye colors. Dark Brown = 20; Blue = 10; Green = 8 ; Light-Brown = 4; Black = 3

I did a tree diagram and I multiplied the values for each, for example: P(D.Brown)= $\frac{20}{45} \cdot \frac{19}{44} = 0.19$

After that, I don't know what to do..

edit: i forgot to mention that it says (draw without replacement)

Comment: Just go color by color and add.  What's the probability that they both have dark brown eyes, say?

Comment: the probability that they both have dark brown eyes is 0,19 ; Blue = 0,5 ; Green = 0,03; Light-Brown = 0,06 and Black = 0,03. So you say that the answer is just the sum of these ?

Comment: The sum of it would be 0,81 , so 81% ?@lulu

Comment: Try a smaller problem you can do by listing all the cases. Suppose, say, $5$ people, $2$ with blue and $3$ with brown eyes. Count the pairs that match and divide by the total number of pairs. Then generalize.

Comment: That seems too high.  Blue, for instance, should be $\frac {10}{45}\times \frac 9{44}=\frac 1{22}$.  Why would you think it was $.5$?

Comment: @EthanBolker with smaller problems, I don't have any problems. It is just that I have to do this problem where there are more than 2 eye colors, which causes me difficulties, because i have never done anything with more than 2 possibilities...

Comment: @lulu you are right, that is the cause why I had doubts, I see that it is 0,05 (rounded up) and not 0,5. Then it is 36% , which looks better in my opinion, but is that the answer to the question? by the way, i added (draw without discount) in my question. Does that matter?

Comment: Note:  it's not clear (at least not to me) what it means to "draw without discount".  Do you mean "without replacement"?  Or, possibly, "with replacement"?

Comment: I wouldn't round, at least not at this stage.   No need for it.

Comment: @lulu that just means that you pick one person first, and then a second one without returning the first person back to the crowd. Do you understand? which is why we did for example 20/45 and then 1 less -> 19/44

Comment: Right, so I think the more common phrase would be "without replacement".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86903/discussion-between-larry-and-lulu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right so far, but like you said you need to do more.
20/45*19/44= **19/99** (dark brown eyes)
10/45*9/44= **1/22** (blue eyes)
8/45*7/44= **14/495** (green eyes)
4/45*3/45= **1/165** (light brown eyes)
3/45*2/45= **1/330** (black eyes)
Now add all the answers up
19/99+1/22+14/495+1/165+1/330= **136/495**
or in decimal form around **0.2747**, or **27.5%**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86972/discussion-on-answer-by-the-confused-person-we-choose-2-different-people-what).